# Implementing a custom Schedule control using a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create my own schedule control basically (very simple), where I want to use a datagridview to display the columns needed and I need the row headers to display specific times (ex. 7 a.m - 10 p.m : 7am,8am, 9am... 9pm, 10pm) in intervals for each hour. I am developing a windows form and I am using an Access database. Along with getting the header rows to display the specific times that I stated above, since this is suppose to act like a schedule viewer, I will need to somehow be able to link my "time" column in my access database to correspond and display within the correct time slot. Below is an example of how I want my datagridview to look..

[image]

This is being using to schedule appointments so it will be possible to have 2-3 data entries where the time would be 1:00 so I need the row Headers to span 2-4 rows but for each record in my databases that has a time of 1:00 or 1:30 I would need it to line up correctly with the 1:00 row header.

I do not have any code yet attempting to convert a datagridview into a schedule control because I am not sure if this can be done and I am not sure how to go about linking the database to the row headers. If it is possible for me to achieve this can anyone give me advice on a) How to create my row Headers so that the time in my "TIME" column will correspond? and b) How do I get the times to link between row header and database column? Would the linking between the times be something done in the code behind where I could give a range and then assign it to the appropriate row header?

Comment: Here are 3 free/open source calendar/sched controls: [1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winformscalenda/ ) [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar) and [3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12201/Calendar-DayView-Control)  they will probably get you where you want to go faster than a DGV

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will look into these and see if i can get them to work